# populate hashmap from hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, hashmap, hibernate-mapping

```
public List<UMRDTO> getDocumentLink(Session session)

{
    List<UMRDTO> documentationList = null;

        Query query = null;
        query = session.createQuery(UMRSQLInt.DOCUMENTATION_LIST);
        documentationList = query.list();


    return documentationList;

}
```

Whenever I restart my app all the hashmap are empty and no data is present that in inputed earlier

I need to get the list i.e objectName , objectType and the documentationLink from the above query and then put the data (objectName,documentationLink) in the HashMap if the objectName is Domainname then the data to be put in domainDocumentationMap or if it is combo then in domainComboDocumentationMap

```
private static Map<String, String> domainDocumentationMap = null;
private static Map<String, String> domainComboDocumentationMap = null;

static
{
    domainDocumentationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    domainComboDocumentationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

}

public static Map<String, String>  getDomainDocumentationMap(){
    return domainDocumentationMap;
}

public static void setDomainDocumentationMap(String objectName, String documentationLink) {
    MMTUtil.domainDocumentationMap.put(objectName, documentationLink);

    }
```

what query shall i write?

Comment: Are you saving data in the database? If yes, are you initializing map while application startup?